# 'row.names' is not a character vector of length

Tags: r, dataframe

I am simply trying to create a dataframe.

I read in data by doing:

```
>example <- read.csv(choose.files(), header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

The data contains 2 columns with 8736 rows plus a header.

I then simply want to combine this with the column of a dataframe with the same amount of rows (!) by doing:

```
>data_frame <- as.data.frame(example$x, example$y, otherdata$z)
```

It produces the following error

```
Warning message:
In as.data.frame.numeric(example$x, example$y, otherdata$z) :
 'row.names' is not a character vector of length 8736 -- omitting it. Will be an error!
```

I have never had this problem before. It seems so easy to tackle but I cant help myself at the moment.

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In any case try: `data_frame <- cbind(example$x, example$y, otherdata$z)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Overview

As long as the `nrow(example)` equals `length(otherdata$z)`, use [`cbind.data.frame`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) to combine columns into one data frame. An advantage with `cbind.data.frame()` is that there is no need to call the individual columns within `example` when binding them with `otherdata$z`.

```r
# create a new data frame that adds the 'z' field from another source
df_example <- cbind.data.frame(example, otherdata$z)
```